# What is the actual purpose of that nested class?

Tags: java

I am a newbie in Android programming and have little confusion in following code.
This portion of code is from android developer site:

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public FeedReaderContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
        ...
    }
}
```

I read some articles about nested classes in Java documentation and some other blogs and understood following reasons to use nested class:

1. Provides better encapsulation.
2. If a class is concerned with only one another class, then we better would make nested class of these two.

But here, I could not figure out anything to use nested class.

What exactly is the purpose of making nested class?

Comment: Better to Search on _Google_.

Comment: Nested class have access to fields of host class

Answer (score 2):

This particular nested class is used as a *namespace* for `String` constants related to its main class.

- It is `abstract`, so it's not intended for instantiation
- It implements `BaseColumns` interface, which is essentially a way to "dump" string constants into the `FeedEntry` class

> Why did they used nested class instead of free-standing class?

Use of a nested class underscores "semantic closeness" of the inner class to its outer class. It cnveys to the readers of your code that `FeedEntry` can be interpreted only in the context of `FeedReaderContract`. Otherwise, `FeedEntry` is meaningless. Essentially, this is done for the human readers of code, because in this case there would be no difference to the compiler.

Comment: I have no problem with abstract and Basecolumns interface ,I understood them pretty clearly. I just want to understand logic for using this nested class.

Comment: @RaazDhakal If you understand what is going on, what part of their logic do you not understand? Why did they use a nested class as opposed to a free-standing class? Or is it something else?

Comment: Yah, why did they used nested class instead of free-standing class??